# After-effects check for value in array

Tags: arrays, date, if-statement, after-effects

I have a weather map template. And I'd like the moon icon to change automaticaly to full moon on certain dates.

So I need expression to check if today's date is part of some array or list or how is it called.

So I made one text layer, that displays current date

```
D = new Date(Date(0));
D.getDate() + "/" + (D.getMonth()+1) + "/" + D.getFullYear()
```

And I applyed this expression to opacity of the full moon icon

```
d = thisComp.layer("theDateLayer").text.sourceText;
vis = transform.opacity;
year = 2013;
fullM = ["27/3","25/4","25/5","23/6","22/7","21/8","19/9","19/10","17/11","17/12"];

if (d == fullM"/year")
vis = 100
else
vis = 0;
```

But its not working. I guess its because the date would have to be same as the whole array. I need to write that I only need any item thats in it. How?

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What are you trying to accomplish with the statement `d == fullM"/year"`?  I think you might be trying to do something like this:

```
d = thisComp.layer("asdf").text.sourceText;
year = "2013";
fullM = ["27/3","25/4","25/5","23/6","22/7","21/8","19/9","19/10","17/11","17/12"];


for(var i = 0; i < fullM.length; i++) {
    if(d == fullM[i] +"/"+ year) {
        100;
        break;
    } else {
        0;
        break;
    }
}
```

...assuming that the `sourceText` of that layer is a string that will be equivalent.  My code uses a for loop to traverse the fullM array.  You should read up on [JavaScript for loops](http://www.w3schools.com/js/js_loop_for.asp).

Comment: I couldn't make it work :/ What I was trying to acomplish with that "/year" was just to save my time typing and retyping those values in array to 27/3/2013 ...

Comment: I've updated my answer, I can confirm that it is working on my computer.  In the future, please include the error you're getting so the person answering your question has some help understanding the problem.

Comment: Awesome! Thanks a lot. I still don't quite understand the mechanics of loops, but it works perfectly. Thanks again and next time I'll make sure to include all I know in my posts.